# how to replace certain text in hyperlink

Tags: java, android, html

It is on Android and need to fix up the html before loaded into the WebView.

normally it could be done by

```
(<a[^>]+>)(.+?)(<\/a>)
```

to get group $1 then replace the text.

What if there are other unknown children inside the <a> tag? 
the example below has <a><p>... text</p></a>, but the <p> could something else not known.

Really what it wants is to replace only the content of text element of any child inside the  element.

```
<a href="http://news.newsletter.com/" target="_blank">
  <p><img alt=“Socialbook" border="0" height="50" 
  src="http://news.newsletter.com/images/socialbook.gif" width="62">
  THIS IS THE TEXT NEEDED TO REPLACE<p>
</a>
```

Can this be done inside the JAVA or has to be done inside the WebView's javascript?

Comment: $regex = "~>[\w\s]+?<~";

Comment: don't use regex for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use any Java html parser. E.g. [JSoup](http://jsoup.org/):

```
String html = "<html><head><title>First parse</title></head>"
    + "<body><a href="..."><p>Parsed HTML into a doc.</p></a></body></html>";
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
Elements links = doc.select("a");
for (Element link : links)
    link.text("~" + link.text() + "~");
```

See [Element](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html) api docs.

Comment: good suggestion, any sample to show how to apply change to all of the text content element?

Comment: found a sample at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30425002/how-i-can-replace-text-in-the-each-tag-using-jsoup
copy here.

Element entry = doc.select("div").first();
    Elements tags = entry.getAllElements();
    for (Element tag : tags) {
        for (Node child : tag.childNodes()) {
            if (child instanceof TextNode && !((TextNode) child).isBlank()) {
                System.out.println(child); //text
                ((TextNode) child).text("word"); //replace to word
            }
        }
    }