# Replace string with jsoup only in text portions

Tags: java, jsoup

I have found several topics with similar questions and valuable answers, but I am still struggling with this:

I want to parse some html with Jsoup so I can replace, for example,

```
"changeme"
```

with

```
<changed>changeme</changed>
```

, but only if it appears on a text portion of the html, no if it is part of a tag. So, starting with this html:

```
<body>
<p><a href="http://changeme.html">test changeme app</a></p>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

I would want to get to this:

```
<body>
<p><a href="http://changeme.html">test <changed>changeme</changed> app</a></p>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

I have tried several approaches, this one is which brings me closer to the desired result:

```
Document doc = null;
try {
    doc = Jsoup.parse(new File("tmp1450348256397.txt"), "UTF-8");
} catch (Exception ex) {
}

Elements els = doc.body().getAllElements();
for (Element e : els) {
    if (e.text().contains("changeme")) {
        e.html(e.html().replaceAll("changeme","<changed>changeme</changed>"));
    }
}
html = doc.toString();
System.out.println(html);
```

But with this approach I find two problems:

```
<body>
<p><a href="http://<changed>changeme</changed> .html">test
    <changed>
        changeme
    </changed> 
app</a></p>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

1. Line breaks are inserted before and after the new element I am introducing. This is not a real problem as I coul get rid of them if I use #changed# to do the replacing and after the doc.toString() I replace them again to the desired value (with < >).
2. **The real problem**: The URL in the href has been modified, and I don't want it to happen.

Ideas? Thx.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is my solution:

```
String html=""
    +"<p><a href=\"http://changeme.html\">"
    +   "test changeme "
    +   "<div class=\"changeme\">"
    +     "inner text changeme"
    +   "</div>"
    +   " app</a>"
    +"</p>";
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
Elements els = doc.body().getAllElements();
for (Element e : els) {
    List<TextNode> tnList = e.textNodes();
    for (TextNode tn : tnList){
        String orig = tn.text();
        tn.text(orig.replaceAll("changeme","<changed>changeme</changed>")); 
    }
}

html = doc.toString();
System.out.println(html);
```

TextNodes are always leaf nodes, i.e. they do not contain more HTML elements. In your original approach you replace the HTML of an element with new HTML with replaced `changme` strings. You only check for the changeme to be part of the TextNodes contents, but you replace every occurrence in the HTML string of the element, including all occurrences outside TextNodes.

My solution basically works like yours, but I use the JSoup method `textNodes()`. This way I don't need to typecast.

P.S.
Of course, my solution as well as yours will contain   `&lt;changed&gt;changeme&lt;/changed&gt;` instead of `<changed>changeme</changed>` in the end. This may or may not be what you want. If you do not want this, then your result is not any more valid HTML, since `changed` is no valid HTML tag. Jsoup will not help you in this case. However, you can of course replace in the resulting string all `&lt;changed&gt;changeme&lt;/changed&gt;` again - outside JSoup.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the added explanation about TextNodes.

Answer (score 5):

I think your issue is that you're replacing the elements html rather than just its text, change:

```
e.html(e.html().replaceAll("changeme","<changed>changeme</changed>"));
```

to

```
e.text(e.text().replaceAll("changeme","<changed>changeme</changed>"));
```

the line breaks issue can probably be solved by doing `doc.outputSettings().prettyPrint(false);` before doing `html = doc.toString();`

Comment: That was some of the first things I tried, but it does not work, all html tags are lost. The output would be: `<body>test <changed>changeme</changed></body>`. But <a hfref ...>, <p> ... are gone. However, the prettyPrint(false) worked fine, thanks. It's kinda odd, as this is a port from Python's lxml, and there prettyPrint is set to true.

Answer (score 2):

Finally I tried this solution (at the end of the question), using TextNodes:

[How I can replace "text" in the each tag using Jsoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30425002/how-i-can-replace-text-in-the-each-tag-using-jsoup)

This is the resulting code:

```
Elements els = doc.body().getAllElements();
for (Element e : els) {
    for (Node child : e.childNodes()){
        if (child instanceof TextNode && !((TextNode) child).isBlank()) {
            ((TextNode)child).text(((TextNode)child).text().replaceAll("changeme","<changed>changeme</changed>"));
        }
    }
}
```

Now the output is the expected, and it even does not introduce extra break lines. In this case prettyPrint must be set to True.

The only problem is that I don't really understand the difference of using `TextNode` vs `Element.text()`. If someone wants to provide some info it will be much appreciated.

Thanks.